# Declaring global variables in ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a set of classes in ActionScript. I need to create a variable (possible global variable) so that I can use the same variable across all classes in my project. How can I create such a variable and use it in this manner?

Comment: bfore downvoting give me some reason.

Comment: Have you even considered googling first? For example: "actionscript global variable" would get you a number of results, that descibe solutions on how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably don't want global variables. Objects are the encapsulation of the program's state in AS3, and objects are the accepted way of doing what you seem to want to do.

I.e. instead of having global variables you would have hierarchy of objects, where the data pertaining to the state lives on one of the levels of the hierarchy.

AS3 doesn't have any good tools for working with global variables, but has moderately advanced tools for working with objects, this is why the use of global variables is discouraged. Regardless, what you can do is like this:

1. Have a file with the name of the variable you want (foo.as for example).
2. Place it in the directory of your package (for this purpose `tld.my.package`).
3. Put the following code into the file:

   `package tld.my.package { public var foo:Object; }`

Here, you have a global variable. You can only have one per file, you cannot turn it into a set/get pair.